# Unusual kernel upgrade behaviour Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: apt, upgrade, kernel, 22.04

I recently ran an `apt upgrade` on my system with the following specs:

**Kernel:** 5.19.0-32-generic
**Distro:** Ubuntu 22.04.2

And I observed some unusual behaviour during the kernel upgrade

#### Standard behaviour:

When running `apt upgrade`, a new kernel version is installed and the current kernel remains unaffected. When running `apt autoremove`, the previous kernel is removed so only two kernels are present. Older kernel versions are never downloaded when using `apt upgrade`.

#### Current behaviour:

Both kernels 5.19.0-35-generic and 5.15.0-67-generic were installed, and when I ran `apt autoremove`, only kernel 5.15.0-60-generic was removed, leaving three kernels installed in the system.

#### Question:

Why is the 5.15 kernel being distributed again while the distro has migrated to 5.19? Why are three kernels kept instead of two? In this case, 5.15.0-67-generic, 5.19.0-32-generic, and 5.19.0-35-generic.

Thank you all for your help, and have a nice day.

Comment: Different kernels may not be compatible with each computer. So older kernels are kept for older computers. and the duplicates are installed as a backup.

Comment: The kernels are stored in the repositories. So if any bug in a newer version they can revert to and older kernel version.

Comment: Ubuntu 22.04 LTS has two main kernel streams; the GA kernel is 5.15 for the life of the product, and HWE changes using kernels from later non-LTS releases meaning it recently switched from 5.15 to 5.19 (from 22.10).  If you have GA & HWE kernel stacks installed (*not just a single one*), you'll keep 5.15 & whatever the HWE kernel is (*currently 5.19, next will be 6.1 some months away*) as well.  FYI:   There are also OEM kernels too, I've limited this common to what I consider the main GA & HWE kernel stack choices - https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/LTSEnablementStack

Comment: @guiverc Thank you very much for your explanation. The link you provided was highly informative as well.

Comment: @guiverc I never explicitly enabled the HWE stack, however I upgraded from an install of Ubuntu 20.04 which enables the HWE stack by default as per the link you shared. Thus, I was automatically enrolled for the HWE stack and also the GA stack when I upgraded to 22.04, and I realized it just now since 5.19 was distributed very recently. Thank you again for clarifying my doubts.

Comment: FYI: Ubuntu 22.04 LTS Server defaults to the GA kernel stack, Ubuntu 22.04 LTS Desktop defaults to HWE kernel stack, with Ubuntu 22.04 LTS *flavors* the ISO used to install controls the state (just as with Ubuntu 18.04 LTS Desktop & earlier; eg. Lubuntu 22.04 & 22.04.1 media will default to GA, however Lubuntu 22.04.2 & later media defaults to HWE kernel stack).  The difference between stacks is not a setting, but the packages installed; so if you *release-upgraded* from a prior release; you'll keep whatever stack(s) you had prior to *release-upgrade*.   (*I used Lubuntu only as example..*)